# Electrical theory regarding load sharing

Tags: frequency, parallel, generator, theory, sharedbus

I am having issues understanding why raising frequency of one AC generator while in parallel with another causes it to pick up more load. Any help would be appreciated.

I operate with turbine powered ac generators in parallel and understand that raising on the speed of one machine will cause it to assume more load. My understanding is that ac machines in parallel sine waves should be in sync. Do they fall out of sync or does speeding up one machine change the speed of the other?

Our generators operate with speed drops if that is of any importance.

Comment: These sound like induction machines and not permanent magnet machines, is that true?

Answer (score 2):

As user @Bryan has noticed in his comment, knowing the principle of the generators helps to understand what happens if only one of the generators is accelerated. Bryan said that looks like the AC generators are induction machines (=asynchronous), not ones with permanent magnets (=synchronous).

I guess he's right because in parallel running synchronous generators with separate motors should have some security mechanism which doesn't allow on a whim tests where one of the generators is accelerated. That's because a synchronous AC generator can be seen as a voltage source (with some type dependent series impedance). If you have 2 of them in parallel they should produce exactly the same waveform and voltage. Otherwise the generators feed current through the other.

If one accelerates one of parallel synchronous generators very slowly the other may succeed to act as a motor and gets accelerated, too without dropping out of sync (=no permanent frequency difference is developed, only increased phase difference). Then only the load of the accelerated generator grows because it drags along the other generator and its motor. Disastrous strong (or at least fuse tripping) currents between the generators may start if it happens that the phase difference grows so high that the sync is lost.

BTW. Preventing dropping out of sync in a network of parallel synchronous generators is a major task in power grid management.

Induction machines can work in parallel as generators. The machines have common load. The load must have a capacitor in parallel to make the generator action to start (=excite), but that's true also for a single induction type generator. The generators must run faster than the synchronous speed to make them to output electricity. Nothing as disastrous is caused by different speeds of parallel generators as it would be the case if the generators were synchronous ones.

No synchronization is needed. The loading is distributed between the generators depending on how fast they run if the generators are identical. The faster of the parallel generators outputs more current than the one running slower. That's because the bigger is the negative slip the more power the generator outputs.

What's the actual AC frequency depends on the structure of the motors, the loading, the parallel load capacitance and what are the running speeds of the generators. Math analysis of parallel generators is quite tricky. It's done here based on the common transformer type equivalent circuit of induction machines: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1018363918306007

It's useful only if one understands the transformer-like equivalent circuit of induction machines including how negative slip introduces apparent negative resistance as the math model of power sourcing of the generator.

The equivalent circuit is presented for ex. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_generator BTW. It's very useful to read at first the theory of induction motors.

Dropping out of sync happens also with induction generators. If one increases the rotation torque to get more power than what's designed possible the maximum in the torque vs negative slip curve is passed and the generator operation weakens radically and the rotation speed jumps. The case is like mirrored how induction motor suddenly slows down or even gets stalled if its mechanical max load is exceeded.

What happens to the AC frequency can be difficult to predict. But keeping a certain beforehand decided frequency even in the normal operation of generators needs a control system or a strong enough synchronous generator in the network of parallel generators.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Two power generators connected to a shared load. Image source: [State Library of Victoria](https://www.flickr.com/photos/statelibraryofvictoria_collections/6758058469) - Creative Commons licence.*

In much the same way as the generators in your question, if either of the riders decides to raise the frequency he will pick up more load. The other rider will find the task of cycling much easier and can maintain the new frequency with less work.

Note that on the bike the cranksets are connected by chain rings without freewheels so they must stay in perfect synchronisation. This is where the analogy breaks down a bit. On the electrical system one may start to lead the other and introduce a phase shift causing current to flow between the generators.

Comment: Love the analogy, should prove useful for training!

Comment: Now let's replace the bicycle with a 1000 t train and the mental image would be even better, to explain why no actual acceleration or deceleration happens.

Answer (score 0):

*I deal with this sometimes, please correct if I'm explaining it wrong.*

When you raise the frequency of the generator the controller will give more throttle. More throttle causes the engine or turbine to produce more torque.
If unhindered this will just cause more speed.

When a (synchronous) generator is on the grid there are two rotating magnetic fields.
One from the grid on the stator and one on the rotor. The excitation provides this.

When these two fields are identical, such as same speed, the generator provides 0 power.

When the engine applies more torque, the rotor field want to move "forward", it wants to push the field of the grid "forward". Which it can't because the grid is a lot bigger.
The result is that this torque becomes power on the grid. Because Torque * Speed = Power.

The opposite can also happen. The reverse power protection should trip the generator breaker.

Extra:
The strength of the magnetic field is important for the voltage and reactive power. The exaction system takes care of this. If the field of the rotor is stronger than the stator, reactive current is produced. Overexcited. And vice-versa for underexcited.

> Our generators operate with speed drops if that is of any importance.

That is important for the control system because your buttons change the "frequency" setpoint.
If the grid is 50 Hz and you set your controller to 50.01 Hz, it will open the throttle until it measures 50.01 Hz.
However, when attached the grid your generator would to have to speed up the entire synchronous grid by 0.01 Hz to get there. Which it obviously can't.
So a droop curve is used that lowers the actual setpoint used by an amount proportional to output power of the engine to prevent the controller from going full throttle.